# Combination of MATCH AGAINST AND REGEXP

Tags: mysql, regex

```
SELECT *,
       MATCH (name,
              tag) AGAINST ('keyword1 keyword2') AS accurat
FROM table_company
WHERE (name REGEXP 'keyword1 | keyword2'
       OR tag REGEXP 'keyword1 | keyword2')
  AND apg_status=1
ORDER BY accurat DESC
```

upper is my search query. anyone can tell me is this a good practice? because i want to search by word and sort by accuracy of the result.

Comment: use explain and you will see what's being done. Moreover for such cases it is good to use search engine like ElasticSearch if possible.

Answer (score 1):

What you have will be miserably slow -- `OR` and `REGEXP` are both slow; all rows will be tediously scanned.

Use `MATCH...` in the `WHERE` clause instead of the or+regexp.

If the `MATCH` needs some further refinement...  (Eg, the `MATCH` gets too many rows, but a `LIKE` or `REGEXP` could filter out some stuff.)  Then do

```
WHERE MATCH ...
  AND ((other filtering conditions))
```

This is efficient because the optimizer will always(?) do the `FULLTEXT` part in preference over the other.  And `FULLTEXT` is *much* faster than `LIKE` or `REGEXP`.

`ORDER BY accurat DESC` -- This is OK, but you may quibble with the order it picks.  Too bad; it's what it is.

Side note...  If you are using InnoDB's `FULLTEXT`, you need to remove any 'words' that are too short or are in the stopword list.  Else the `MATCH` will fail.  (This is a change from MyISAM.)